# How can I improve my question which is attracting close votes?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43564476/what-parts-do-i-need-for-a-object-instance-registry-pattern-in-python

I see there are two close votes on my post, but there aren't any comments to suggest how I can improve my question.

Can someone give me a clue?

Comment: If you click on the "close" link, you should be able to see what your post has been close voted for. That should give you a place to start.

Comment: Though after a quick read through (and without knowing the technology, so there might be something else I'm missing) it looks like it might be a combo of asking for opinions ("What makes a good object instance Registry pattern in Python?" is likely not going to have an objective answer) and it _looks_ like you have working code and just want a review to make it better. If those two points aren't what you want, there's a place to start.

Comment: @Kendra, huh. when I click on 'close' I just get the option to close my own post?

Comment: @Kendra, also. It sorta works. There are just so many idioms and patterns I don't know about (always learning something new) I thought something might be obviously missing or misguided. For example, I'm not sure if nesting the dictionary class inside of the registry class is really a good idea from a few opinions I've read about nested classes. But rather than asking this question over again, I thought a pattern related question would be more to the point, cuz, you know, it depends.

Answer (score 5):

You've explained what you're trying to do and shown your code.  That's good, but then you follow it with the question "What makes a good object instance Registry pattern in Python?"  That's a matter of opinion, so your question is likely to be closed.

Is your approach not working in some way? Asking about that might make a good question for Stack Overflow. Asking a broad, open-ended question is off-topic.

Comment: Oh. So the solution is "close enough" that it's not clearly wrong. Then I guess no answer is an answer in that case (>_<)

Comment: @xtian No, that's not really what I'm saying. Your first step to finding out if your code works should be to run it, not to show it to other people to ask them if they think it will work. We're not likely to run your code for you and test it out if you don't ask a specific question.

Comment: @ Bill the Lizard. The code does run. There are a few things I don't like, ex. at various points my instances have the class of the Report data class and other times has the class of the dictionary in the Registry and not the Registry itself. SO...It's gonna take time and thought to work those out--and I will. At the same time I don't want to reinvent the wheel; that's where a design pattern comes in handy. Right?